# How to handle/capture a long press in windows store apps

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-8, gesture, long-press

Could anyone tell me how to capture a long press for a windows store app in C#?
I can used a "tapped" gesture no problem but when I replace 
`TappedRoutedEventArgs` with `HoldingRoutedEvent` it just doesn't register a holding gesture.
I'm testing this with my laptop so could it be that it doesn't recognize a mouse holding event?

I'm assuming there's similar functionality for the windows phone 7 but they're mostly for Silverlight which isn't used for Windows 8.
Any links/examples would be a great help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Holding Event:

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Holding="Grid_Holding_1">
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
private void Grid_Holding_1(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("You held at" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

You are correct about the mouse not firing the holding event.  Run it in the simulator and then you can use the "Basic Touch Mode" to simulate the hold.

Comment: Thanks John! Cleared up my problem perfectly. Didn't realise there were different touch options for the simulator. Maybe you could help me a bit further. Since the simulator doesn't pick up mouse holding gestures, is there a different way to capture this? As in some more code to handle mouse gestures? 
I find the API a bit difficult to understand in this area so thought it would be better to ask here!

Comment: @AimeeJones If you want to use mouse events you can use the PointerPressed and PointerReleased events.  To accomplish a similar effect with the mouse you could start a timer in the PointerPressed event and cancel it in the released event.  If it fires before it is cancelled then they held the mouse pointer down.

Comment: Ah I thought it was something along those lines. Thanks again for your help!